# Closed subset of R^2

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Show that the set A = {(x,y): $x^3$ $>=$ $y^5$} is closed as a subset of $R^2$.

I defined a closed set as a set whose complement is open.

So the complement of the above set is {(x,y): $x^3$ $<$ $y^5$} = {(x,y): $x^3$ - $y^5$ $<$ 0}

I am trying to use the theorem that uses the inverse image of a open set is open, but I am not sure how to incorporate it into the proof.

Answer (score 3):

The function $f(x,y)=x^3-y^5$ is continuous. Consider the preimage of some appropriate set.

Answer (score 2):

Define $f(x,y)=x^{3}-y^{5}$ then $A=f^{-1}([0,\infty))$.

Comment: wouldn't it be $A=f^{-1}((-\infty,0))$. since I trying to show $x^3$ - $y^5$ < 0 produces an open set, which would then show A is closed?

Comment: That's also okay. The reason I chose this set is because the preimage of a closed set under a continuous function is closed.